# filter dataframe in a for loop for a period of two months with 1 day increasing

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp

I am trying to filter dataframe by 2 months window. I have a dataframe of 4 months.

Sample dataframe:

```
Index                 val      Datetime
2017-11-01 14:30:00  536.04 2017-11-01 14:30:00
2017-11-01 15:00:00  533.04 2017-11-01 15:00:00
...                     ...                 ...
2017-12-31 10:00:00  145.02 2017-12-31 10:00:00
2017-12-31 10:30:00  145.92 2017-12-31 10:30:00
```

I tried this:

```
df2[df2['Datetime'] < df2['Datetime'].min() + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months = 2) + Timedelta('%sD' %x)]
```

output:

```
2017-11-01 14:30:00  536.04 2017-11-01 14:30:00
2017-11-01 15:00:00  533.04 2017-11-01 15:00:00
...                     ...                 ...
2017-12-31 10:00:00  145.02 2017-12-31 10:00:00
2017-12-31 10:30:00  145.92 2017-12-31 10:30:00

2017-11-01 14:30:00  536.04 2017-11-01 14:30:00
2017-11-01 15:00:00  533.04 2017-11-01 15:00:00
...                     ...                 ...
2018-01-01 10:00:00  145.62 2018-01-01 10:00:00
2018-01-01 10:30:00  151.50 2018-01-01 10:30:00
```

The datafame is increasing by 1 day but but the start day is fixed.

I want to shift dataframe by 2 months with each increasing day.

expected output:

```
2017-11-01 14:30:00  536.04 2017-11-01 14:30:00
2017-11-01 15:00:00  533.04 2017-11-01 15:00:00
...                     ...                 ...
2017-12-31 10:00:00  145.02 2017-12-31 10:00:00
2017-12-31 10:30:00  145.92 2017-12-31 10:30:00

2017-11-02 14:30:00  536.04 2017-11-02 14:30:00
2017-11-02 15:00:00  533.04 2017-11-02 15:00:00
...                     ...                 ...
2018-01-01 10:00:00  145.62 2018-01-01 10:00:00
2018-01-01 10:30:00  151.50 2018-01-01 10:30:00
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample with expected output?

Comment: @jezrael, added it.

Comment: @jezrael, anything possible?

Comment: Not sure if understand you.

Comment: i want to iterate over the dataframe and filter the data of 2 months every time the date changes.

Comment: So output is list of DataFrames? What is expected output with sample `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='20D'))` ? (be free change it if necessary.)

Comment: @jezrael, can you please look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985139/rearrange-columns-on-the-basis-of-count-anf-alphabetically-read-description-for

Comment: sorry, I am on vacation, so on phone only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,it should use the filter with scope.(replace days '12' with variables as need):

```
import dateutil
from datetime import datetime,date,timedelta  
df2[(df2['Datetime'] > df2['Datetime'].min() + timedelta(days=12))  & (df2['Datetime']  < df2['Datetime'].min() + timedelta(days=2) + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=2))]
```